# How to redirect my brand new domain to Dlinkddns.com

Tags: domains, redirects, dns, domain-registration, godaddy

Today I bought a domain from GoDaddy for my personal usage. I'm trying to forward requests from the domain to a DlinkDDNS account with no success so far.

`https://account.dlinkddns.com:port` works great. I can access the server behind my router. The same request using the domain isn't working `https://www.example.com:port`.

On GoDaddy the domain is set to forwarding with masking. I'm wondering if the redirection is immediate or if it can take a few hours/days to be effective. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Go DADDY forwarding + masking is HTTP redirections and URL Frame.**

http://help.godaddy.com/article/422

**If you want to make other ports than https or https to work, you need to make a CNAME in your DNS settings.**

http://help.godaddy.com/article/680#cnames

**Once you setup up a CNAME correctly, the answer to your question will be :**

You can also use the dig command to check the TTL time about the records, you will see exactly when that record will expire and the new values fetched from the further queries.

(fake results)

```
dig www.example.com

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.example.com.        3265    IN  A   123.256.289.001
```

Now you know that from this example, the next fetch from the DNS servers specified in YOUR computer (normally your ISP servers) will be in 3265 seconds. (this is an exemple TTL, it is a countdown)

To be sure you configured it correctly, you can dig directly the NS servers.

```
dig NS example.com
```

Check the ANSWER section

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.com.        60  IN  NS  ns1.exempledomain.com.
example.com.        60  IN  NS  ns2.exempledomain.com.
```

Now try to query the ns server to check if your new settings are applied correctly.

```
dig @ns1.exempledomain.com www.example.com
```

And check for a CNAME to account.dlinkddns.com

Hope this helps

Comment: CNAME was the key. Thanks for the links. It's working.

Answer (score 0):

If the forwarding with masking is what is called CNAME otherwise then this should work fine, and for your second question yes, this depends on the TTL value of your records i.e. whether they are 1 day, 1hour etc.

you can check via nslookup on your computer if its resolving it correctly.

```
Default Server:  your.dns.server.
Address:  X.X.X.X

> set q=cname
> www.example.com
Server:  your.dns.server
Address:  X.X.X.X

Non-authoritative answer:
www.example.com canonical name = account.dlinkddns.com

>
```